# NullReferenceException with namespace reference in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to modify another script called ResourceBank from a script called ResourceManipulation.

I Try to use namespace to reference ResourceBank but it causes nullReferenceException when i
use unity UI (TMP) button to activate "public void ManipulateResources()" part.

Debugger says that line "ResourceBank.instance.moneyAmount += moneyToBeGained;" triggers the NRE;

Any idea how to not cause nullreferenceException when activating "public void ManipulateResources()"?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using pyrryr.caps.resourcebank;

namespace pyrryr.caps.resourcemanipulation
{
    public class ResourceManipulation : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public ResourceManipulation instance;
        private void Awake()
        {
            instance = this;
        }

        private ResourceBank ResourceBank;
        
        public int moneyToBeGained;
        public int moneyToBeLost;
        [Space(10)]
        public int suppliesToBeGained;
        public int suppliesToBeLost;
        [Space(10)]
        public int securitysuppliesToBeGained;
        public int securitysuppliesToBeLost;
        [Space(10)]
        public int sciencesuppliesToBeGained;
        public int sciencesuppliesToBeLost;

        

        public void ManipulateResources()
        {
            ResourceBank.instance.moneyAmount += moneyToBeGained;
            ResourceBank.instance.moneyAmount -= moneyToBeLost;
            ResourceBank.instance.suppliesAmount += suppliesToBeGained;
            ResourceBank.instance.suppliesAmount -= suppliesToBeLost;
            ResourceBank.instance.securitySuppliesAmount += securitysuppliesToBeGained;
            ResourceBank.instance.securitySuppliesAmount -= securitysuppliesToBeLost;
            ResourceBank.instance.researchSuppliesAmount += sciencesuppliesToBeGained;
            ResourceBank.instance.researchSuppliesAmount -= sciencesuppliesToBeLost;
            ResourceBank.instance.UpdateResources();
        }       
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using pyrryr.caps.resourcemanipulation;

namespace pyrryr.caps.resourcebank
{
    public class ResourceBank : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public ResourceBank instance;
        private void Awake()
        {
            instance = this;
        }

        public int moneyAmount;
        public TMP_Text moneyAmountText;

        public int suppliesAmount;
        public TMP_Text suppliesAmountText;

        public int securitySuppliesAmount;
        public TMP_Text securitySuppliesAmountText;

        public int researchSuppliesAmount;
        public TMP_Text researchSuppliesAmountText;

        //Resource Modifiers

        

        public void UpdateResources()
        {
            moneyAmountText.text = moneyAmount.ToString();
            suppliesAmountText.text = suppliesAmount.ToString();
            securitySuppliesAmountText.text = securitySuppliesAmount.ToString();
            researchSuppliesAmountText.text = researchSuppliesAmount.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! `unityscript` is or better was a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now! Your script is clearly `c#`!

Answer (score 0):

`NullReferenceException` means one of the objects you reference isn't set to anything. So in your `ManipulateResources` function, either `ResourceBank` is null, or `ResourceBank.instance` is null (you can see which one by setting a breakpoint and hovering over).

Whatever is supposed to set your `ResourceBank` member doesn't do its job, or `Awake()` is never called.